# Smooth scrolling in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a `GridView` inside my pageroot. It's very wide, and scrolling works fine, but it's not at all a smooth form of scrolling. It scrolls in ticks.

How can I solve this in my markup code?

Comment: That's usually due to the virtualization of the unerlying items. You could change the GridView's ItemsPanel from VirtualizingStackPanel to a StackPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doh!

The `ItemsPanel` property of the `GridView` was set to a `VirtualizingStackPanel`. Changing it to `StackPanel` solved my issue.